# an iterated integral question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

This iterated integral is proving harder than I thought. Evaluate by reversing the order of integration: 
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{y=x}^{\sqrt{x}}\frac{\sin y}{y}dy\right)dx
$$

Comment: No, it's not hard. What precisely do you have when you switch the order?

Comment: Upon switching the order, I get $$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{x=y}^{x=\sqrt{y}}\frac{\sin y}{y}\right)dy$$, which can be reduced to $$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{\sin y}{\sqrt{y}}-\sin y\right)dy$$. What's the antiderivative of the first term under the integral symbol?

Comment: @transcendental What did you get? It does not show up in the comments.

Comment: Better to add it to your original post!

Comment: true, I am learning!

Comment: Please draw pictures every time. If $y=\sqrt x$, please think about what $x$ is!

Comment: Thank you. A picture of the region is essential.  I get $$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{x=y^2}^{y}\frac{\sin y}{y}dx\right)dy$$ which is easy to solve....

Comment: Yippee! Now remember the lessons! :)

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#00f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{\int_{x}^{\root{x}}{\sin\pars{y} \over y}\,dy}\,\dd x}
=\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}\Theta\pars{y - x}\Theta\pars{\root{x} - y}{\sin\pars{y} \over y}\,dy}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}\Theta\pars{y - x}\Theta\pars{x - y^{2}}{\sin\pars{y} \over y}\,dy}\,\dd x=
\int_{0}^{1}{\sin\pars{y} \over y}\bracks{\int_{y^{2}}^{y}\dd x}\,\dd y
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{0}^{1}{\sin\pars{y} \over y}\pars{y - y^{2}}\,\dd y
=
\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{\sin\pars{y} - y\sin\pars{y}}\,\dd y
=
\cos\pars{1} + \int_{0}^{1}\bracks{\sin\pars{y} - \cos\pars{y}}\,\dd y
\\[3mm]&=
\cos\pars{1} + \bracks{-\cos\pars{y} - \sin\pars{y}}_{0}^{1}
=
\cos\pars{1} + \bracks{-\cos\pars{1} - \sin\pars{1} + 1}
=\color{#00f}{\large 1 - \sin\pars{1}}
\end{align}

Comment: What does represent $\Theta$ ?

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large\Theta\left(x\right)\equiv\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcl}0 & \mbox{if} & x < 0\\[3mm] 1 & \mbox{if} & x > 0\end{array}\right.\qquad}$

It is the [Heaviside Step Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).